active admin form is creating empty records, in nested form

ActiveAdmin.register User do
  form do |f|
    tabs do
      if current_user.has_role?(:admin)
        tab "User Login" do
          f.inputs do
            f.input :email
            f.input :roles
            f.input :employee_type, label: "Joining As", as: :select
            # f.input :is_active
            f.input :password if f.object.new_record?
            f.input :password_confirmation if f.object.new_record?
          end
        end

        if f.object.persisted?
          tab "Official Details" do
            f.inputs "Official Details", for: [:official_detail, f.object.official_detail || f.object.build_official_detail] do |od|
              od.input :company_name, as: :select, collection: OfficialDetail::COMPANY_NAMES, required: false
              od.input :work_location, required: false
              od.input :date_of_join, required: false
              od.input :emp_id, label: "Employee ID"
              od.input :service_code
              od.input :department_name, as: :select
              od.input :shift_timing_start, as: :time_picker, input_html: { value: od.object&.shift_timing_start&.strftime("%H:%M") || "09:00" }
              od.input :shift_timing_end, as: :time_picker, input_html: { value: od.object&.shift_timing_end&.strftime("%H:%M") || "18:00" }
              od.input :designation
              od.input :reporting_manager_id, as: :select, collection: User.reporting_manager_candidates
              od.input :official_email_id, required: false
              od.input :job_summary
              od.input :other_details
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


Requirenments are :

while updating the users details, it is not mandetory to add Official Details of user
but still it is creating below record (most of them are empty )
yes i can put the validation but that will give error while updating the user details


irb(main):042:0> User.find(13).official_detail
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  OfficialDetail Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "official_details".* FROM "official_details" WHERE "official_details"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=>                                                        
#<OfficialDetail:0x000075a8fbbd2c38
 id: 9,
 company_name: "",
 work_location: "",
 date_of_join: Tue, 22 Oct 2024,
 emp_id: "",
 department_name: nil,
 designation: "",
 official_email_id: "",
 job_summary: "",
 other_details: "",
 user_id: 13,
 reporting_manager_id: nil,
 created_at: Wed, 02 Oct 2024 17:30:37.850589000 IST +05:30,
 updated_at: Wed, 02 Oct 2024 17:30:37.850589000 IST +05:30,
 shift_timing_start: 2000-01-01 09:00:00 +0530,
 shift_timing_end: 2000-01-01 18:00:00 +0530,
 service_code: "">


if company_name is empty in the details then dont create a record
  # Validate presence and length of company_name if the official details are present
  validates :company_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }, if: :should_validate?

  # Add other validations as necessary...

  def should_validate?
    user&.official_detail.present?
  end


